# Discard features with small variance, how to do in practice?

Tags: neural-networks, feature-selection

I'm training a neural network for regression. The input vectors consist of $92$ different features, I want to discard features with small variance (standard deviation).

There are two ways that came up to me:

1. Decide the number of features to keep, say $N$. Then keep the $N$ features with the biggest standard deviations.
2. Choose a $\sigma_{min}$, then discard features whose standard deviation is smaller than this $\sigma_{min}$.

For the second approach, I don't know how to choose such a $\sigma_{min}$, there are also two ways that came up to me:

1. Just arbitrarily choose a $\sigma_{min}$, say `1e-5`.
2. Let $\sigma_{min}$ to be $\text{mean}\{\sigma_i\}_{i = 1}^{92}$

Which approach should I choose?

Comment: (I realise that the questions are not identical, but the answers are getting at the same thing)

Comment: My dog has height $10^{-5}:$ is she small or large?  If the units of measurement are millions of centimeters, she is tiny; but if the units are degrees of (Earth) latitude, she is very large.  *Ergo,* "small" is a meaningless attribute of a number like  $\sigma_i$ and (thus) your proposal also is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small or large variances might occur just because the feature ranges are different. For example, while one feature is in range $[0,1]$, the other might be in range $[0,1000]$. The latter will most probably higher variance. So, omitting these *low* deviation features can harm your process seriously from the beginning. If all or your features are in more or less the same range, it might be logical to choose your lower bound for the deviation by looking at their histogram.

Before proceeding, I advise you to pick one of the standard dimensionality reduction or feature selection methods, if your aim is to reduce your number of dimensions.

Comment: If he were to standardize the features first this would not be a problem and his approach is sensible.

Comment: if they were standartized using $(x-\mu)/\sigma$ first, just as in stdScaler class, then all would have the same deviation, and you couldn’t decide based on variances.